# Check the root password

Tags: linux, passwords, root

What is the best way to check if a root linux password is correct,from a c program.One solution is tu run a command like : `echo \"myPass\n"\ | sudo -S mySudoPassword` and somehow check stderr to see if contains data.I am looking forward to get an elegant solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate that a given password is correct for a given username using the shadow file.

See [Given a linux username and a password how can I test if it is a valid account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035093/given-a-linux-username-and-a-password-how-can-i-test-if-it-is-a-valid-account) for the mechanics of how this is done.  It should be possible to perform the same operations in a C program.

Comment: but I can't the shadow file,if i am not root or at least my acoount is in the sudoers file.I want to check just for the root...not for every user.